# Determine in what module a class resides

Tags: powershell, add-type

I have some code that works a treat in the ISE, but fails in a script. It fails where I use `[System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface]::new()`, and this is a common occurrence, a module that is loaded automatically in the ISE, but needs to be loaded discretely in a script.
So that brings up the generic question, is there a way to start from the type and determine what module is needed? Or is this one of those where you just need to already know and/or be able to mine the Microsoft support documents for the info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface is not a PowerShell module. It is a .NET Framework class. You generally will need to check the documentation for the class to find the Assembly it belongs to. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface) In this case PresentationCore.dll.

You would use AddType to load this assembly.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
```

A search for "find .net assembly from class name" will find some Q&A on this topic, but mostly with C# examples.

Comment: @mike-smith-mct-mvp Dang, I made it harder than it needed to be. But it still begs the question, if all I know is the type I am referencing, say `[System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface]`, is there a way in the ISE to see what module that type is coming from? Or is the support doc the only answer? The fact that the DLL is mentioned at the top of the page and now I know to at least try the file name without the extension is HUGE in any case.

Comment: If the assembly is currently loaded (like in your ISE) then use [System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface] | select Assembly